# How to empty or clear input in angucomplete-alt

Tags: angularjs

i cannot clear dynamically

```js
<angucomplete-alt 
  id="auto-clients"
  placeholder="Select Client"
  pause="100"
  selected-object="vm.curClient"
  initial-value="vm.client"
  local-data="vm.clients"
  search-fields="name"
  title-field="name"
  minlength="1"
  input-class="form-control"
  match-class="text-info" 
/>
```

Can I do it with some event like `function resetFilter() { vm.client = '' };`
?

Answer (score 6):

```
$scope.$broadcast('angucomplete-alt:clearInput')
```

Answer (score 2):

**Clear only one autocolmplete input value**

$scope.$broadcast('angucomplete-alt:clearInput', 'autocomplete input id')